# ymaps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.ready is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run the code, but for some reason it gives an error, you can help

```
useEffect(() => {
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
var suggestView1 = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest');
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the error in your question?

Comment: ymaps__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.ready is not a function